# Remove-TcmPublishTransactions giving error Nullable object must have a value

Tags: sites-9.5

We are using Tridion 9.5 while clearing older Publish Transactions using the Tridion PowerShell command "Remove-TcmPublishTransactions" giving below error

```
Remove-TcmPublishTransactions -Successful
Remove-TcmPublishTransactions : Nullable object must have a value.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-TcmPublishTransactions -Successful
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-TcmPublishTransactions], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Tridion.ContentManager.Automation.Commands.RemoveTcmPub
   lishTransactionsCommand
```

Comment: I guess the "Nullable object must have a value" errors comes from the Core Service. Check your Tridion Event Log to see the full error (incl. Stack Trace).

Comment: hi Abdul Qadir, if the reply is correct, can you please mark is as an approved answer?

Answer (score 3):

For me this happened once also. Somehow some publications got stuck in queue without some mandatory fields in them. I think the data it was missing was the target they were being published to or something similar.

Anyway, you can try few things.
First, you can modify this Remove-TcmPublishTransactions command, and add publication id to it, you can then remove transactions by publication, or by status and narrow it down.

Second, you can try creating a core service script to delete these transactions, it really simple.

If that does not work, you can contact RWS support, send them your table export, and they will provide you with scripts to delete them from the database.